# Timer not stopping when executing "clearInterval" multiple times

Tags: javascript

I have created a timer using setInterval in JavaScript, and my resetButton code is below. When the user clicks the reset button once, everything works as planned. However when the user clicks the reset button twice or more, the timer won't stop when the reset button is clicked.

I have tried to make it so that the button doesn't register multiple times when it's clicked multiple times, but that didn't solve the problem.

Any ideas as to why it's doing this and any solutions?

Thank you

```
$("#reset").click(function (event) {
    if (!event.detail || event.detail == 1) {
     console.log("test");
     promptId = 0;
     userMinutes = 0;

     //stops timer
     clearInterval(interval);
     setTimer(0);

     timerDropdown.selectedIndex = 0;
     textDropdown.selectedIndex = 0;

     matchedText(true);
     wordsPerMinute();

     originTextContent.innerHTML = "Please Select Your Prompt";
     testArea.value = "";
     // allows users to type after textArea is disabled
     testArea.disabled = false;

     testWrapper.style.border = "10px solid grey";
     if (warningMessage.firstChild)
      warningMessage.removeChild(warningMessage.firstChild);

    startDefaultTimer();
  }
});

function startDefaultTimer() {
 testArea.addEventListener(
  "input",
  () => {
   if (promptId != 0 && userMinutes != 0) {
    // Converting minutes to milliseconds
    startTimer(userMinutes * 60 * 100);
   }
  },
  { once: true }
  );
 }
```

Comment: Please remove extraneous code till you have a minimum working example, step through it in Dev Tools, and if you are still stuck, please explain exactly what the actual vs. intended result is and what you have tried to solve it.

Comment: Post the code for `startDefaultTimer()` You probably aren't assigning the intervalId to a global variable or something.

Comment: Sorry, i added the startDefaultTimer(). I set the interval as a global variable since it needs to be used in different functions.

Comment: Your click event always add new event listener to `input` and it stacks, so that's what makes multiple calls to `startTimer`

Comment: Not related to your specified issue, but you has a typo(!) in your milisecond converting code. `userMinute` should be multiplied by `60 * 1000` not `60 * 100`.